# What is the breathe path?

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

> The following steps are required to integrate breathe functionality:
>
> 1. Add the breathe path to your conf.py by adding the following line:
>
> ```
> sys.path.append("/home/me/docproj/ext/breathe/")
> ```
>
> <sub>https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html</sub>

**What is this breathe path** and how do I find it on my system?

I installed breathe as a Python package, i.e. with `pip3 install breathe`, so is that supposed to be the Python package "Location" value, as reported by `pip3 show`, e.g.:

```
$ pip3 show breathe
Name: breathe
Version: 4.35.0
Summary: Sphinx Doxygen renderer
Home-page: https://github.com/michaeljones/breathe
Author: Michael Jones
Author-email: m.pricejones@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: docutils, Sphinx
Required-by:
```

?

There's no breathe executable:

```
$ which breathe
$
```

That example value in the quickstart guide doesn't at all look like the Python `dist-packages/` directory, and I wasn't able to find anything that explained it at https://breathe.readthedocs.io/.